# How to convert string to mongoose.Types.ObjectId in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just add a field like this in **modelSchema**

```
receiverId:[{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UserChat' }]
```

In controller:

```
var recievedIds = [];
recievedId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(recievedId);
recievedIds.push(recievedId);
console.log(typeof recievedId);
messageInfo.receiverId = recieverIds;
new UserChat(messageInfo).save().then((info)=>{
        res.send(info);
    }).catch((infoError) =>{
        res.send('FAILED_TO_SEND_MESSAGE');
    });
```

It is giving type as **object** not as ObjectId
and also it is pushing **empty array** into *mongodb*
i tried removing new infront of mongoose in the above object creation
Can anybody help me how to create a ObjectId?

Comment: Can you add a console.log for both the `receivedIds` and `receivedId`?

Comment: It is giving  [vnksgvsb38yevwju73h] for recievedId and for recievedIds it is returning vnksgvsb38yevwju73h like this it is returning in console

Comment: If I log type of it is returning object for both

Comment: Can you log `infoError` and add it to the question?

Comment: it would never log something like `ObjectId. what are you trying to achieve by the way ?

Comment: @Usman Rana actually, I'm trying to pass some ids related to message recipients from postman as a JSON object. I want to process the JSON object from req.body and send a message to all recipients

Answer (score 0):

As the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) states: An ObjectId must be a single string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters.

Please verify that your `receiverId` meets that requirement.